# How to change color of 'more' icon in app bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have added an app bar in my application. As shown in the image, my app baar contains almost all elements' color as white, but the only color of 'more' icon (highlighted in red)  is black. Please suggest how to change its color to white.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your styles you have to add this line:

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/yourColor</item>
```

Have a look at [this](http://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2014/10/28/android-changing-the-toolbars-text-color-and-overflow-icon-color/) site for further explanation.